# Find element in an array that may or may not exist

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a document that looks a bit like this:

```
> db.orders.find()
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  _reminders: [{
    notified: true,
    timestamp: ISODate(),
    completed: false
  }]
}
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  _reminders: []
}
```

What I am trying to find is a document in the orders collection where the "reminders" does not contain a reminder in a specific time range, and is not completed.

```
db.orders.find({
  '_reminders': {
    $elemMatch: {
      completed: false,
      timestamp: { $ne: time }
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that this will not find an order which does not have any reminders at all.

How would one query this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want

```
db.getCollection('Clock').find({
$or : [
    {
        _reminders : {
                $elemMatch : {
                    timestamp : {
                        $lte : ISODate("2019-07-12T15:35:32.278Z"), 
                        $gte :  ISODate("2012-07-12T15:35:32.278Z") 
                        },
                    completed : false
                }
        }
    },
    {
       _reminders : {$size : 0}     
    },
    {
       _reminders : {$exists : false}
    }
]
```

})

Answer (score 2):

you should use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query.

`db.orders.find({$or: [ { _reminders: [] },  here_put_your_query_with_time_match ]})` - it will return both documents which match your query and these with empty _reminders